question about sequence convergence
I have never formally studied real analysis, so the following question may be quite naive to some of you.
Consider a sequence of real number $x_{n}$ which converge to $x$. So given a $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $|x_{n}-x|<\epsilon$. Also, since $x_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, given a $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N'\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m>n\geq N'$, $|x_{m}-x_{n}|<\epsilon$. The thing I want to ask is, is there always a common $N$ so that both $|x_{n}-x|$ and $|x_{m}-x_{n}|$ smaller than given $\epsilon$ for all $m>n\geq N$?
I mean it is pretty intuitive, but I feel like I am missing here. Can anybody enlighten me the proof, or provide counter example if it is not true?

The answer is yes, and it's a fairly simple thing to prove if we use the triangle inequality.
Choose $N$ such that $|x_n - x| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then if $m, n \geq N$, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray} |x_n - x_m| & = & |(x_n - x) + (x - x_m)| \\
& \leq & |x_n - x| + |x - x_m| \\
& = & |x_n - x| + |x_m - x| \\
& < & \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
& = & \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}$$

So in this case, is $|x_{n}-x|$ always strictly smaller than $|x_{m}-x_{n}|$?

Not necessarily. This just bounds the worst case, which is where $x_m = x + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $x_n = x - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (or vice versa). You can just as easily have, for example, $x_m = x_n$ for some values of $m$ and $n$.

I guess for my purpose, the worst case is also fine. Thank you for your reply.

If the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergence then it is also a Cauchy sequence. But a Cauchy sequence may be not convergence.

The sequence being consider is in $\mathbb{R}$, which is a complete metric space. And every Cauchy sequence converges in a complete metric space

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Oh, Yes, I didn't read carefully. If the  Cauchy sequence is in a complete metric space then it is convergent.
